# SQL/BigQuery on github samples

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pom.xml

I'm using the google bigquery tool, I'm trying to select ALL sample github repositories that have a pom.xml file and within the content of the file, have an artifact id ex-ex e.g 
`<artifactId>ex-ex</artifactId>`

For this I have broken it down into 2 steps:

1) Find all pom.xml files

`SELECT sample_repo_name FROM 'bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_contents' WHERE sample_path LIKE 'pom.xml'`

2) Select the repositories which contain ex-ex artifact (in the content table)

`AND content LIKE '%ex-ex'`

The 2nd part of the query does not work (no results found) and is likely due to some syntax error somewhere. Full query below:

`SELECT sample_repo_name FROM 'bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_contents' WHERE sample_path LIKE 'pom.xml' AND content LIKE '%ex-ex' LIMIT 1000`

Would really appreciate help with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `'%ex-ex%'`?  Without the second `%`, you are only searching for records whose last 5 characters are `'ex-ex'`.  Adding `content` to the `select` in your first query and spot checking a few results, the `content` field appears to be XML (pom.xml, duh) and seem to end with `</project>`, and thus will probably never match with `'%ex-ex'`.